# Fontforge python implementation won't accept unicode value in glyphpen definition

Tags: python, fontforge

I'm trying to convert a CAD font file to ttf for use with HTML using Python and Fontforge.

The program reads the fontfile data:

```
    data=f.read(4)
    glyph['offset']=f.tell()
    glyph['glyphname']=data[1]*256+data[0]
    glyph['pathsize']=((data[3]<<8)&0xff00)+(data[2]&0xff)
```

(Forgive the weird manipulation of the data bytes: I have been trying various ways of inputting the data in case there's something I'm doing wrong).

I then define the glyph by creating my character

```
    uniname=glyph['glyphname']
    char=font.createChar(uniname)
    pen=font[uniname].glyphPen()
```

This works fine until I get to the unicode character 260, when pdb tells me that there is a TypeError: Index out of bounds.

The funny thing is that, if I run the following instead:

```
    for i in range(253,280):
      uniname=i
      print(uniname)
      char=font.createChar(uniname)
      pen=font[uniname].glyphPen()
```

Then it happily accepts all the values without complaint.

I'm baffled.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this to work.

Instead of doing this:

```
char=font.createChar(uniname)
pen=font[uniname].glyphPen()
```

I did this:

```
char=font.createChar(uniname)
pen=char.glyphPen()
```

In the first example, the glyph is created for the uniname character using `font.createChar()` and the pen is assigned from the font's list of characters.

In the second example, the gyph is created as before, but the pen is assigned directly and I no longer get the 'index out of bounds' error.

I have no idea why this works, but hope it will help someone else with similar issues.